# Meteor qa and production sites do not match

Tags: meteor

We're running into a problem with 2 of our meteor projects. We have a QA environment and a Production environment for our applications on the meteor cloud. We deployed the same code branch (master) to each of our sites, yet we have a bug happening in one that isnt happening in the other.

Does anyone know what might be causing such an issue? Does meteor maybe update certain packages behind the scenes that we don't know about? Is there a way to check for package mismatch between 2 sites?

Comment: How do you deploy? Are both servers 100% equal (in terms of containers, server env., database state)?

Answer (score 1):

A few things we need to know first:

1. Both environments were created with the same dependencies, do they
   have the same version of `meteor`, `nodejs`?
2. How are you doing the deployment? on a `server directly` or using
   `docker` for example?

I recommend you join the `Meteor Community` on [Slack](https://join.slack.com/t/meteor-community/shared_invite/zt-1gbgfk5g0-KtnmKNJH%7ElU5xOBP4OFXiw), they are very active and you will get help.